# Disable localization in Xcode file template headers

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

Xcode will generate the file header based on the file template like the following:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//___COPYRIGHT___
//
```

But the date will be generated based on my computer's locale setting (Traditional Chinese), and I don't like that.

I want everything in my code to be in English only.

Is it possible to make it happen?

I am using Xcode 7.1 + Swift